# Backup not working on a newly installed Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: backup, deja-dup

I apologize, I have asked this before, but I thought that I would reinstall Ubuntu, and now I can't find my original question.

I recently installed ubuntu 14.04. I then tried to restore my backed up files.
I have been using the default backup 'deja dup.' My backups are on an external
drive and encrypted.
It works for a very short time. I can see that it has restored a few of the files which sit in my home directory. Then it stops and logs me out. At this
point the back up seems to stop. The last time I tried, I watched the details, and it seemed that it was restoring files in .config when it stopped.
I don't get an error message. At least, I don't get one which I have time to read before being logged out. 
Please advise. 
thanks
Jack

Comment: Run your restore attempt under `script` (`man script`) to probably capture the message.

Comment: Here it is http://askubuntu.com/questions/727319/backup-fails-and-logs-me-out